# Cookies and Sessions setting and getting issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, express, session

I'm facing an issue where I'm setting cookies and session values at login on the backend, which is node js. However, when react calls the API that verifies the cookies or sessions values, the values returns undefined...

I know my middleware is fine because I can log data automatically to the DB, which is MySQL. I have tried switching `req.session.isAdmin`, `req.session.loggedIn` and `req.session.username` to `req.cookies.isAdmin`, `req.cookies.loggedIn` and `req.cookies.username` but that did not work.

The code is below, any advice will truly help. Please note I am trying to configure cookie the best way possible as I am new to setting cookies, any lessons are welcomed!

Index.js

```
require('dotenv').config();
const host = process.env.HOST;
const port = process.env.PORT;
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
const session = require('express-session');
const SqlDbStore = require('express-mysql-session')(session); // Import SqlDbStore
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(
  session({
    key: 'BibleTriviaSessionCookies',
    secret: '3B4F7C4E6DA85A5176758B437A22A',
    store: new SqlDbStore({
      host: process.env.DB_Host,
      port: process.env.DB_Port,
      user: process.env.DB_User,
      password: process.env.DB_Pass,
      database: process.env.DB_Data,
    }),
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
      secure: true,
    },
  })
);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send("The server is running successfully. <br/>The server is running on port " + port + "... <br/>The server url is " + host + ":" + port + "...")
});

const userRoute = require('./routes/User');
app.use('/user', userRoute);

const adminRoute = require('./routes/Admin');
app.use('/admin', adminRoute);

const triviaRoute = require('./routes/Trivia');
app.use('/trivia', triviaRoute);

app.listen(port, (req, res) => (
  console.log("Server running on port " + port + "...")
));
```

Login and CheckLogin Routes from User.Js

```
//Login Page
router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
  const username = req.body.username;
  const password = req.body.password;

  try {
    const userVerification = await db.query('SELECT * FROM userverification WHERE accountUsername = ?', [username]);
    const userLogin = await db.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE accountUsername = ?', [username]);
    const adminVerification = await db.query('SELECT * FROM adminusersverification WHERE accountUsername = ?', [username]);
    const adminLogin = await db.query('SELECT * FROM adminusers WHERE accountUsername = ?', [username]);

    // Check User Verification
    if (typeof userVerification[0][0] !== 'undefined') {
      sg.sendVerification(userVerification[0][0].accountEmail, userVerification[0][0].accountFirstName, userVerification[0][0].accountLastName, username);
      res.json({ message: 'User needs to check email to verify account' });
    }
    // Check User Table
    else if (typeof userLogin[0][0] !== 'undefined') {
      const result = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        bcrypt.compare(password, userLogin[0][0].accountPassword, (err, result) => {
          if (err){
            reject(err);
          }
          else {
            resolve(result);
          }
        });
      });

      if (result === true) {
        req.session.username = username;
        req.session.loggedIn = true;
        req.session.isAdmin = false;
        res.cookie('username', username);
        res.cookie('loggedIn', true);
        res.cookie('isAdmin', false);
        res.setHeader('Set-Cookie-Instructions', 'loggedIn=true; username=username; isAdmin=false');
        return res.json({ loggedIn: true, username: username });
      }
      else {
        return res.json({ loggedIn: false, message: 'Account Does Not Exist or Password Is Incorrect!' });
      }
    }
    // Check Admin Verification
    else if (typeof adminVerification[0][0] !== 'undefined') {
      sg.sendAdminVerification(adminVerification[0][0].accountEmail, adminVerification[0][0].accountFirstName, adminVerification[0][0].accountLastName, username);
      res.json({ message: 'User needs to check email to verify account' });
    }
    // Check Admin Table
    else if (typeof adminLogin[0][0] !== 'undefined') {
      const result = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        bcrypt.compare(password, adminLogin[0][0].accountPassword, (err, result) => {
          if (err){
            reject(err);
          }
          else {
            resolve(result);
          }
        });
      });

      if (result === true) {
        req.session.username = username;
        req.session.loggedIn = true;
        req.session.isAdmin = true;
        res.cookie('username', username);
        res.cookie('loggedIn', true);
        res.cookie('isAdmin', true);
        res.setHeader('Set-Cookie-Instructions', 'loggedIn=true; username=username; isAdmin=true');
        return res.json({ loggedIn: true, username: username, isAdmin: true });
      }
      else {
        return res.json({ loggedIn: false, message: 'Account Does Not Exist or Password Is Incorrect!' });
      }
    } else {
      return res.json({ loggedIn: false, message: 'Account Does Not Exist or Password Is Incorrect!' });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return res.json({ message: 'An Error Occured!' });
  }
});
router.post('/checkLogin', (req, res) => {
  const expectedIsAdmin = req.session.isAdmin; // Get isAdmin from the server's session
  const expectedLoggedIn = req.session.loggedIn; // Get loggedIn from the server's session
  const expectedUsername = req.session.username; // Get username from the server's session

  const receivedIsAdmin = req.body.isAdmin;
  const receivedLoggedIn = req.body.loggedIn;
  const receivedUsername = req.body.username;

  console.log(receivedIsAdmin + ' <-> ' + expectedIsAdmin)
  console.log(receivedLoggedIn + ' <-> ' + expectedLoggedIn)
  console.log(receivedUsername + ' <-> ' + expectedUsername)

  if (receivedIsAdmin === null || receivedLoggedIn === null || receivedUsername === null) {
    //User not logged in...
    console.log("User not logged in...")
    return res.json({forceLogout: false, verified: false})
  }
  else if (receivedIsAdmin === expectedIsAdmin && receivedLoggedIn === expectedLoggedIn && receivedUsername === expectedUsername) {
    // Cookies match the server's session values
    //User verification passed...
    console.log("User verification passed...")
    return res.json({ forceLogout: false, verified: true });
  } else {
    // Cookies do not match the server's session values
    //User verificaton failed...
    console.log("User verificaton failed...")
    return res.json({ forceLogout: true, verified: false });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Cookies should always be set to `false` when working locally so that it can communicate with http protocol. Setting it to `true` as you did will never work on `localhost`. Try this

```
cookie: {
  maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
  secure: false, // false on local, true on dev/uat/prod if its https - you can set this conditionally based on url if it includes https
},
```

Comment: I did try this and set the link to HTTP instead of HTTPS, and that still does not work.

Comment: The question I do have is, since the session info is being stored to the MySQL session table, should it pull the info from that table?